# Inheritance of property methods (set, get, didSet, willSet, etc.) in Swift

Tags: swift, inheritance, properties, getter-setter

**My question is how to deal with inheritance of property methods such as `set`, `get`, `didSet`, `willSet`, ...?**

Let's take an example: I want to override the setter method of a property in a Swift class. Here is what I want to achieve (which is obviously not working):

```
class A {
    var value: Int {get {...} set {...} }
}

class B: A {
    var value: Int {
        set(newValue) {
            // do some fancy stuff...
        }
    }
}
```

This is not working, too:

```
// in class B
override func setValue(newValue: Int) {
    // do some fancy stuff...
}
```

We can do in Swift something like this:

```
class A {
    var _value: Int = 0
    var value: Int {
        get {
            return _value
        }
        set {
            _value = newValue
        }
    }
}

class B: A {
    override var value: Int {
        get {
            return _value
        }
        set {
            _value = newValue + 1
        }
    }
}

let a = A()
a.value = 1
print(a.value) // => 1

let b = B()
b.value = 1 
print(b.value) // => 2
```

This approach is not very elegant because I have to implement also the getter methods, which is actually not necessary, because only the setter should be overridden.

Comment: In your first example, the baseclasses property is stored, while the subclasses one is computed, they have to be of the same kind to do anything with overriding.

Comment: You are right, this is just because for showing the goal.

Comment: @Kametrixom While it is true that you cannot override a computed property with a stored one the other way is possible.

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
class A {
    var value: Int = 0
}

class B: A {
    override var value: Int {
        get { return super.value }
        set {
            // Something fancy...
            super.value = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

While you still have to implement a getter in `B`, you at least don't need `_value`, which helps keeps class `A` clean.

Comment: This makes it cleaner, but the underlaying question is: How to inherit property related methods, such as `get`, `set`, `willSet`, ...

Comment: @MichaelDorner: I might be wrong, but `var value: Int = 0` in the superclass is a *stored* property, so (unless you tag it with `@objc`), it does not have `set`/`get` methods which could be inherited.

Comment: You are right, this was just for demo purpose. The second code is with computed properties.

Comment: But I removed it to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: What if the subclasses have different types for "value" (String, Int, etc...) but you want to be able to set/get the "value" based on the fact that they inherit from a common superclass?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your only way to do this would be to create a separate get and set method if you really wanted to do this.

```
class A {
  private var value: Int = 0

 func getValue() -> Int { return value }
 func setValue(newValue : Int) {
   value = newValue
 }
}
```

By the nature of using computed properties you are basically doing a "shortcut" in some ways over making two separate methods - and as thus you would have to override both the set and get if you wanted to change things.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your usage an override of `didSet` could do the trick (based on your last example):

```
class B: A {
    override var value: Int {
        didSet {
            _value++
        }
    }
}
```